# HSQLDBとTERASOLUNAの接続について

Tags: sql

今回もTERASOLUNAの応用でHSQLDBとの接続を行っています。

環境ベースとしてしているのは
[こちら](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0811/11/news141.html#l_r1201.gif)です。

サイトの手順に沿って進めて起きている現象は、
・サーバーを起動してブラウザ表示するとエラーが起きる
ということです。

以下がエラーログになりますが、主に
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][INFO][[/terasoluna-sample]] サーブレット action を利用不可能にマークします
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][ERROR][[/terasoluna-sample]] サーブレット /terasoluna-sample がload()例外を投げました

というログが原因だとおもわれます。
ネットで検索してみると、一番多いのはstruts-config.xmlに記述等のミスがある
という内容でした。

struts-config.xml内で編集した内容は主にform-beans要素とaction-mapping要素です。
サイトと照らし合わせて、考えられる原因とどこに注力して修正していけばいいかよろしければ
ご教授お願いしたく思います。

```
<!-- ======================================== フォームビーン定義 -->

  <form-beans>
   <form-bean name="_form"
     type="jp.terasoluna.fw.web.struts.form.DynaValidatorActionFormEx">
     <!-- 【I】 -->
     <form-property name="firstTerm" type="java.lang.String"/>
     <form-property name="secondTerm" type="java.lang.String"/>
     <form-property name="resultTerm" type="java.lang.String"/>
   </form-bean>
 </form-beans>


<!-- ======================================== アクションマッピング定義 -->
  <action-mappings type="jp.terasoluna.fw.web.struts.action.ActionMappingEx">

    <action path="/welcome" parameter="/welcome.jsp"/>
    <action path="/concatBL" name="_form" scope="session">
    <forward name="success" path="/resultSCR.do"/>
  </action>

  <action path="/inputSCR" parameter="/input.jsp" />
  <action path="/resultSCR" parameter="/result.jsp" />
  </action-mappings>
```

エラーログ

```
2017/09/13 10:15:35 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
情報: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Users\hironori\Desktop\pleiades\java\6\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/pleiades/eclipse/jre/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/pleiades/eclipse/jre/bin/../jre/bin;C:/pleiades/eclipse/jre/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.16Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Users\hironori\Downloads;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Users\hironori;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ZipGenius 6\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65;C:\pleiades\eclipse;;.
2017/09/13 10:15:35 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol init
情報: Coyote HTTP/1.1を http-8080 で初期化します
2017/09/13 10:15:35 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
情報: Initialization processed in 527 ms
2017/09/13 10:15:35 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
情報: サービス Catalina を起動します
2017/09/13 10:15:35 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
情報: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5.27
2017/09/13 10:15:35 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start
情報: XML検証は無効です
[2017/09/13 10:15:35][INFO][[/terasoluna-sample]] Initializing log4j from [classpath:log4j.properties]
[2017/09/13 10:15:35][INFO][[/terasoluna-sample]] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[2017/09/13 10:15:35][INFO][ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[2017/09/13 10:15:35][INFO][XmlWebApplicationContext] Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 13 10:15:35 JST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
[2017/09/13 10:15:36][INFO][XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
[2017/09/13 10:15:36][INFO][DefaultListableBeanFactory] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@72f864fe: defining beans [jxpathPatchActivator,TerasolunaSampleDataSource,transactionManager,transactionInterceptor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,daoBeans,org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0,messageSource,sqlMapClient,queryDAO,updateDAO,spDAO,queryRowHandleDAO]; root of factory hierarchy
[2017/09/13 10:15:36][INFO][JXPATH152PatchActivator] JXPATH-152 Patch activation succeeded.
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][INFO][ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1131 ms
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][DEBUG][SessionLockControlFilter] interruptResponseCode = 503.
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][DEBUG][SessionLockControlFilter] threshold = 2. LimitedLock is enabled.
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][DEBUG][MessageFormatCacheMapFactory] messageResources.messageFormatClone = dateFormatOnly
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][DEBUG][MessageFormatCacheMapFactory] use MessageFormatCloneReturnAtDateFormatOnlyMap.
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][DEBUG][SpringMessageResources] messageSource MessageSource is used.
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][INFO][ContextLoaderPlugIn] ContextLoaderPlugIn for Struts ActionServlet 'action, module '': initialization started
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][INFO][[/terasoluna-sample]] Initializing WebApplicationContext for Struts ActionServlet 'action', module ''
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][INFO][XmlWebApplicationContext] Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'action-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 13 10:15:37 JST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][INFO][XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/moduleContext.xml]
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][INFO][XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/commonContext.xml]
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][INFO][DefaultListableBeanFactory] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@69c01ba9: defining beans [/welcome,/concatBL,/inputSCR,/resultSCR,concatBLogic]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@72f864fe
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][WARN][XmlWebApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/concatBL' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/moduleContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'concatBLogic' while setting bean property 'businessLogic'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [sample.concatBLogic] for bean with name 'concatBLogic' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/moduleContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.concatBLogic
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:355)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:296)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.init(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:226)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:869)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:336)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [sample.concatBLogic] for bean with name 'concatBLogic' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/moduleContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.concatBLogic
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.concatBLogic
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1386)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1232)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1270)
    ... 41 more
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][INFO][DefaultListableBeanFactory] Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@69c01ba9: defining beans [/welcome,/concatBL,/inputSCR,/resultSCR,concatBLogic]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@72f864fe
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][ERROR][ContextLoaderPlugIn] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/concatBL' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/moduleContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'concatBLogic' while setting bean property 'businessLogic'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [sample.concatBLogic] for bean with name 'concatBLogic' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/moduleContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.concatBLogic
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:355)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:296)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.init(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:226)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:869)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:336)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [sample.concatBLogic] for bean with name 'concatBLogic' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/moduleContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.concatBLogic
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.concatBLogic
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1386)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1232)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1270)
    ... 41 more
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][ERROR][[/terasoluna-sample]] action: null
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/concatBL' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/moduleContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'concatBLogic' while setting bean property 'businessLogic'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [sample.concatBLogic] for bean with name 'concatBLogic' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/moduleContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.concatBLogic
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:355)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:296)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.init(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:226)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:869)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:336)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [sample.concatBLogic] for bean with name 'concatBLogic' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/moduleContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.concatBLogic
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.concatBLogic
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1386)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1232)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1270)
    ... 41 more
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][INFO][[/terasoluna-sample]] サーブレット action を利用不可能にマークします
[2017/09/13 10:15:37][ERROR][[/terasoluna-sample]] サーブレット /terasoluna-sample がload()例外を投げました
javax.servlet.UnavailableException
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:880)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:336)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
2017/09/13 10:15:37 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol start
情報: Coyote HTTP/1.1を http-8080 で起動します
2017/09/13 10:15:37 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
情報: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
2017/09/13 10:15:37 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
情報: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null
2017/09/13 10:15:37 org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreLoader load
情報: Find registry server-registry.xml at classpath resource
2017/09/13 10:15:37 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
情報: Server startup in 2138 ms
[2017/09/13 10:16:44][INFO][[action]] サーブレット action は現在利用できません
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく記事の誤りなどに起因しているのではないかと思います。[このページ](https://github.com/igapyon/diary/blob/master/2008/ig081126.src.md)を読んでみて下さい。

Comment: 確認して指定通りの修正をしたら直りました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決したら、クローズして下さい :-)